# concatenate innerhtml of div into string variable

Tags: php

i tried to concatenate innerhtml of div into string variable:
games variable:

```
$games = '';
```

DOMinnerHTML function:

```
function DOMinnerHTML($element) 
{ 
    $innerHTML = ""; 
    $children = $element->childNodes; 
    foreach ($children as $child) 
    { 
        $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
        $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($child, true)); 
        $innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML()); 
    } 
    return $innerHTML; 
}
```

ExtractFromType function:

```
function ExtractFromType($type)
{
$html = file_get_contents('www.site.com/' .$type);
$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($divs as $div) {
if (strpos($div->getAttribute('style'),'MyString') !== false) {

//////
$games = $games.DOMinnerHTML($div);
//////

}
}
}
```

code:

```
ExtractFromType('MyType');
echo $games; // = Nothing.
```

this code return nothing.

Comment: You should do some basic debugging first and find out at which point exactly your code fails. Does `$html` contains the expected result? Remove the `@` before `loadHtml`, you might be missing some important errors. Do you ever get into your `if` statement?

Comment: yes i checked my if statement , when i tried `echo DOMinnerHTML($div);` its working.

Comment: i defined $games before the DOMinnerHTML function.

Comment: Yes. `$games = '';`. It's empty. So `echo $games` prints an empty string. You should enable error reporting in your script. The error is clearly pointed out by PHP: *PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: games in /Users/mimbert/Public/workspace/php/test.php on line 36*

Comment: i fix it with global $games,$links; thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`$games` is defined in the global scope, and it's not available inside `ExctractFromType`. Define it inside the function, then return the value:

```
function ExtractFromType($type) {
  $html = file_get_contents('www.site.com/' .$type);
  $dom = new domDocument;
  @$dom->loadHTML($html);
  $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
  $divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

  $games = '';
  foreach ($divs as $div) {
    if (strpos($div->getAttribute('style'),'MyString') !== false) {
      $games = $games.DOMinnerHTML($div);
    }
  }
}

echo ExtractFromType('MyType');
```